# tkinter present the values from a list to entry widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

Using tkinter in the gui I'm building an array made of entry boxes. In some columns of the array I'm entering values which i read them and build a list for every column. There are also columns without values which are readonly in which I want to export results from lists. I can't find how to make the program to show the results.

Keep in mind that i have two defs one for building the widgets and one for the calculations.

In order to build one empty-results column I make this:

```
self.akt_b =[]
    for i in range(12):
        akt_b =StringVar()
        self.akt_b =Entry(self, textvariable =akt_b, width =10,
                                  state='readonly', readonlybackground ="white")
        self.akt_b.grid(row =7+i, column =3)
```

which makes visually what I want.
Then I calculate a list_b of 12 float numbers which I want to show in self.akt_b
I'm trying:

```
for i in range(12):
        self.akt_b[i+1].delete(0, END)
        self.akt_b[(i+1)].set("round(list_b[(i+1)], 2)")
```

which doesn't work
I've tried also .insert not again, I've tried akt_b nothing again

what can I do?

Comment: _"...which doesn't work."_ So, are you getting an error message, or what? Also, on one line you're doing `self.akt_b =[]` and on another line you're doing `self.akt_b =Entry(...)`. If you're trying to create a list of Entries, that's not how it works. There should be a `self.akt_b.append(...)` in there somewhere.

Comment: that was it, thank you very much! I was using the .append on other list of entries, but somehow i didn't used it in this one

Answer (score 2):

after Kevin's answer I found out the solution, I was missing the .append argument.

Just in case anyone is interested here is the solution:

```
self.akt_b, self.entries =[], []
    for i in range(12):
        akt_b =StringVar()
        entries =Entry(self, textvariable =akt_b, width =10,
                                  state='readonly', readonlybackground ="white")
        entries.grid(row =7+i, column =3)
        self.akt_b.append(akt_b)
```

so now

```
for i in range(12):
      self.akt_b[i].set(round(list_b[i], 2))
```

works perfect.

Sometimes brain just seems to stop...